# How to generate logs with timestamp in sikuli?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I want to generate logs with time stamp being in place of popups i have mentioned.
Please suggest some steps for generating logs with time stamp.

**Code:-**

```
click("1450851018693.png")
wait(2)
click(Pattern("1450851091319.png").targetOffset(1,2))
click(Pattern("1450851555941.png").targetOffset(-201,1))
type("111")
click(Pattern("1450851201892.png").targetOffset(-13,2))
type("121")
wait(1)
if exists ("1450851253342.png"):
    popup("start button is enabled")
    click("1450851253342.png")
```

In the above code instead of popups i want the messages to be logged in file with time stamp.
Please Help..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `logging` module from Python importing it and getting a logger instance:

```
import logging
FORMAT='%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger=logging.getLogger('')
```

Then, use it in you code (per default, level `info` is not printed to the console, but `warning` is)

```
logger.warning('My message')
```

You should have a log entry in your like:

> 2016-03-07 13:10:43,151 My message

See [Logging Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) for description and basic tutorial.